# Qgis creating point within complex shapes (with holes)

Tags: qgis, features, point-in-polygon, centroids

[image]I'm looking for a tool to create a point in every polygon, that will be placed in the polygon. these are complex shapes with holes. the point must not put in those holes!

the "plugin RealCentroid"  should do that, but that does not work.

I can get points, on every weight-point, but that is not always inside of a polygon!!

Comment: If you add a diagram describing what you want (and do not want), you will likely get very useful answers.

Comment: In ET geowizards for Arcmap there's an option to create centerpoints "within". That might do what you need.

Comment: Martin, I searching for a Qgis method

Comment: The QGIS Plugins Repository lists realcentroid which is guaranteed to create points within the polygons. https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/realcentroid/

Answer (score 1):

[Here I found my question!](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32025/is-it-possible-to-create-a-point-within-a-polygon-not-a-centroid)

I found the way to fix my problem, so this question is answered! (Vector -> ResearchTools -> Random Points)

Comment: You can accept your own answer if you want to. It is still useful because people reach the question through different search terms.